# Подскажите софт для измерения активности жесткого диска

Tags: память, железо, диск

Пишу программу для работы с внешней памятью. Надо как-то узнавать насколько она эффективна. Для этого надо запускать ее на жестком диске с установленными файликами-тестами и чем-то мерять насколько диск повернулся в ходе одного запуска.

1. Форматировать диск и загружать файлики и программы заново надо перед каждым запуском?
2. Чем измерять вращение диска?
3. Каковы будут погрешности измерения?

P.S. В компьютере два диска. На первом ОС и прочее, второй собираюсь использовать для указанных целей.

Comment: А зачем мерять вращение? Многочисленные кэши по всему компьютеру и фоновые задачи помножат смысл измерений на ноль.

Comment: @andreymal то есть то, что диски разные это не исправит?

Comment: Ну фоновых задач может и не будет, а кэширование на всех уровнях и планирование системой ввода-вывода всё равно будут влиять

Comment: Хотя на самом деле рассуждать о вращении вообще нет смысла, ведь скорость вращения — величина постоянная и указывается в характеристиках диска

Comment: "Установленные файлики тесты" подразумевают что у вас есть файловая система и работать с ней вы видимо собираетесь через ОС. А тогда вы не можете предугадать как файл физически лежит на диске, он может быть фрагментирован. Так что вращение и прочие физические параметры не имеют смысла в задаче с файлами. Да и вряд ли про вращение даже на прямом доступе к железу вы что то узнаете. Диску дается команда на выполнение операции, он сам запускает цикл чтения в момент когда нужный участок постоянно вращающегося диска пролетает под головкой

Comment: нормальные тесты возможны только при прямом доступе к железу без использования средств ОС. Ну или с использованием низкоуровневых средств самой ОС на котором понятий "файл" и "форматирование" (мы же про логическое, диск на физическом уровне на заводе отформатирован и трогать его не надо, если нет проблем с поверхностью) опять же не существует

Comment: @Mike а что это за низкоуровневые средства?

Comment: А это от конкретной операционной системы зависит. в linux например работают с файлом устройства и используют ioctl для специфических операций, например отключения кеша ОС. В windows не знаю, гуглить надо. например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522644 похоже то же как с файлом можно работать. И искать подходящее WinAPI для специфических операций

Comment: А вот это ты читал? https://habr.com/ru/post/154235/

Answer (score 0):

Измерять конкретно **вращение диска** смысла нет по той простой причине, что все современные диски вращаются со своей паспортной скоростью (5400, 7200, 15000) оборотов в минуту. Минимальные погрешности компенсируются электроникой диска и системой позиционирования, любое серьезное отклонение - и диск просто перестает работать.

Скорость можно прочитать через SMART, также, она как правило написана на этикетке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]